# While printing a HTML page extra zeros are being added

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am trying to print below 3 three from HTML page; problem is @a.Invoice.TotalAmount is traling 4 extra zero after a number for eg to 12 it displays as 12.0000 to 18.54 it displays a 18.5400 and 11.1 as 11.1000.

```
<tr>
        <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left; font-size: 12px;">@a.Invoice.InvoiceVendor.Name</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px;">@a.Invoice.InvoiceNumber</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px;">@a.Invoice.TotalAmount</td>
    </tr>
```

When I debug the code (html) page zeros are not being displayed.
[image]

But When I print the page it is coming with trailing zeros

[image]

My concern is I don't need zeros after decimal. Any suggestions please?

Thanks.

Comment: what datatype are you using?

Comment: I don't know what "@a" is. Also, I don't see any C# or JavaScript code but this is tagged with C# and JavaScript. I also don't know what "print the page" means; it is not clear if "print" means HTML or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying it with the JavaScript method toFixed(2)

eg.

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
```

read more: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp